# WPF: Command hindering button to enable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command

I have 2 buttons.. at the beginning one of them is enabled and the other is not. Then I have 2 commands for these buttons which I need to implement keybindings for them. These commands should also replace the click-methods for the buttons.

When the first button is clicked the second button should become enabled. But it is not working. If I remove the command of the second button and add a click-method instead it works..

**xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="first" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="second" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource first}" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_1" />
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource second}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="F4" Command="{StaticResource first}" />
        <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{StaticResource second}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{StaticResource first}" x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Command="{StaticResource second}" IsEnabled="False" x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="312,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    namespace WpfApplication1 {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window {
            public MainWindow() {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
                MessageBox.Show("Test");
            }

            private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
                e.CanExecute = button1.IsEnabled;
            }

            private void CommandBinding_Executed_1(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
                button1.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When `CanExecute` is defined, the button is en- or disabled based on the value of `e.CanExecute`, therefor setting `IsEnabled` explicitly has no effect, since it is set implicitly.

You could introduce a variable that is returned by `CommandBinding_CanExecute` - this would have the desired effect as far as I can tell.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    // other details elided

    bool _enableButton1 = false;

    private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
        e.CanExecute = _enableButton1;
    }

    private void CommandBinding_Executed_1(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        enableButton1 = true;
    }
}
```

Anyway, you could elide the `CanExecute`-action altogether and just set `IsEnabled` explicitly. This will do the trick as well.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    // elided

    private void CommandBinding_Executed_1(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        button1.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't elide CanExecute and rely on the IsEnabled property of the button because then the command can be executed by the key-shortcut. But you're right .. I could add a variable and bind the IsEnabled property of the button to it.

Comment: Alright, I see. Glad I could help anyway. Please let me know if it worked out for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Why Button.IsEnabledDoesNotWork?** Thought it was setting in XAML

because Command Overrides the IsEnabled functionality. 
[image]

```
  public partial class SampleWindow : Window
    {
        private bool _isButton1Enabled = false;
        public SampleWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }

        private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                e.CanExecute = _isButton1Enabled;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }


        private void CommandBinding_Executed_1(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _isButton1Enabled = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this exaclty what I have written?